# Convergence or divergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1+\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have problem in determining the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1+\frac{1}{n}}$. It seems like it is convergent given that $(1+\frac{1}{n})>1$ for all n, but I still cannot prove it rigorously.

Can anyone help me ??

Comment: Consider $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and try to asymptotically compare $a_n$ with the general term of your sum.

Comment: @AmihaiZivan Couldn't one state it's divergent because $\frac{1}{n}\le\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1+\frac{1}{n}}$ for all $n$ and $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent?

Comment: 1. It is divergent (since the harmonic series is divergent).
2. Your inequality is incorrect.

Comment: @AmihaiZivan I informally meant "for all $n$" to mean $\{n: n\ge 1\}$. My apologies.

Comment: @Limitless Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Comment: @Limitless You  still might want to change the inequality since  $n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}\geqslant n$. It shows that direct comparison with the harmonic series wont work and you need to calculate the limit of their ratios.

Comment: @AmihaiZivan Argh. I forgot how to do arithmetic. I'm sorry.

Comment: This question has been answered very recently: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/266547/51594

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F(k%5E(1%2B1%2Fk)),+k%3D1..infinity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} n^{1/n} = 1. $$

Thus we have

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{1+1/n}}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)}= 1. $$

Now you can apply the limit comparison test to conclude that the series diverge to $+\infty$.